# Items in UINavigationBar not filling width of screen

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

When I first load my view controller, I set up some buttons and a title for my UINavigationBar.  If I load the screen in portrait, everything looks great.  However, if I load the screen in landscape, the buttons only take up part of the space provided.  When I rotate to portrait and back to landscape again, the items are now correctly expanding to fill the space on the NavBar.

The NavBar itself is added manually in storyboard.  It is set to autosize and stretch and Autoresize Subviews is checked.

What can I do to make it always correctly display the navigation bar?

Relative setup code is displayed below.

```
UIBarButtonItem * saveBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(setField)];
UIBarButtonItem * cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelClicked:)];

UINavigationItem * buttonsItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];


NSString * title = [self.data objectForKey:@"title"];
if(title){
    buttonsItem.title = title;
} else {
    buttonsItem.title = @"Default Title";
}

[buttonsItem setLeftBarButtonItem:cancelBtn animated:YES];
[buttonsItem setRightBarButtonItem:saveBtn animated:YES];
[navBar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: buttonsItem, nil] animated:YES];
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:
Some additional info that I had previously forgot to mention.

I am not loading this screen through a segue, instead I am doing this:

```
DiaryCalendarPickerViewController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"diaryCalendarForm"];
 ...           
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Initial load into landscape

[image: Initial load in landscape]

Rotate to portrait

[image: Rotate to portrait]

Rotate back to landscape

[image: Rotate back to landscape]

Comment: Could you add some screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

After you layout your view but before setting nav items try calling

```
[buttonsItem.titleView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

Comment: Neither of these seemed to work for me. I don't think the UINavigationItem works because of the way I manually added the nab bar.  Additional information has been added to the post.

Comment: Does DiaryCalendarPickerViewController inherit from UINavigationController? And if so why the need to manually add a navbar? The code for setting the bar button items should be in the viewDidLoad of whatever view is pushed onto your Navigation Controller

Comment: It inherits from UIViewController.  I believe it doesn't get the standard NavBar because it is being presented instead of being pushed.

Comment: I was assuming you were using a navController, I would guess that since the storyboard / nib is set in portrait, that it inits the navBar to the wrong frame size.  See my answer

Comment: Well, you led me to the right answer. The UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth wasn't needed for my, but I moved my setup code from ViewDidLoad to ViewDidAppear and it is now spacing correctly.

Comment: Good deal, glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue exactly , and your comment cain is the right answer , for whom have the same issue , to fix it but the code for right bar button or right navigation bar item into ViewDidAppear and it will work like charm !